# Does SCOM agents enqueue data if there is no network connection?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, windows-server, scom

I wanted to ask does SCOM agents enqueue data like alerts if there is no network connection? Does it use MSMQ for it? What if MSMQ is dead?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!  Performance data is retained on the managed agent. Once connection is restored, data points are further updated onto the Operational DB.